# I'm invisible until I'm lost

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My first ever try at a riddle, hope you guys enjoy!

> I'm invisible until I'm lost.
>
> Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.
>
> Among the newborn I stay.
>
> Until they learn how to slay.
>
> Two faces have I
>
> One is true and the other to lie

**What am I?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My guess is

> Innocence

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> You are normally not aware of your own innocence until you lose it.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> This could be referring to losing your status as an innocent citizen and being found guilty in a court of law.

Among the newborn I stay.

> Newborns are born innocent in all ways, hence the phrase "as innocent as a newborn".

Until they learn how to slay.

> Children lose their innocence when they do something bad, e.g, mercilessly killing an insect or spider.

Two faces have I

 One is true and the other to lie

> The face of innocence can often be identified very clearly, as with a newborn babe. To "look innocent" or "have an innocent face", on the other hand, is normally a tactic employed to cover up the fact that one has done something bad.

Comment: Nice one! Very spot on answer

Answer (score 7):

You are a:

> Coin

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> You don't give much attention to small change until you lose it. "I have to find that damn penny!"

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> Obviously you are poorer when you lose money.

Among the newborn I stay.

> The very young do not know how to spend money.

Until they learn how to slay.

> Unsure about this, might refer to knowing how to spend as we get older, or using coins to play arcade games when we aren't too young anymore.

Two faces have I

> Two sides of a coin

One is true and the other to lie

> Heads or tails, heads is positive or true, and "to lie" is negative, referring to tails

Answer (score 6):

My try:

> Calm / Calmness

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> usually calmness is not noticed until someone loses it.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> You most probably do something stupid when losing calm.

Among the newborn I stay.

> Kids are calm. (They only cry when they need something)

Until they learn how to slay.

> But starting from about 2yo they are not anymore (believe me, I know)

Two faces have I

One is true and the other to lie

> Some people are calm (maybe because they already know who to blame when something goes wrong) and that's a true state of calmness, others are calm waiting to burst out and this one is the lie.

Comment: *“There are three things all wise men fear: the sea in storm, a night with no moon, and the anger of a gentle man.”* -Patrick Rothfuss, The name of the wind. (in my language is translated to the anger of a *calm* man)

Comment: @lois6b Demons run when a good man goes to war. Night will fall and drown the sun, when a good man goes to war. Friendship dies and true love lies, night will fall and the dark will rise, when a good man goes to war.

Comment: @randal'thor. Wise words Melody Pond.

Comment: Idk though, the last line seems a bit of a stretch

Comment: @BlueFire, I cannot contradict you here, but it helped get 2 awesome comments.

Comment: Haha, yes very true

Answer (score 2):

My try:

> Darkness

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> Darkness (false statement) is invisible (not realized), until someone prove it.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> You will pay for light

Among the newborn I stay.

> Newborn is surrounded by evil peoples (darkness)

Until they learn how to slay.

> Until they learn how to do evil things too

Two faces have I One is true and the other to lie

> One is true = real meaning of darkness, no light, 
>  the other to lie = another meaning of darkness.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> Identity

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> We take our identity for granted. We are unable to have an truly objective view of ourselves and our identity. The only true way of being objective of our identity is to look at ourselves from the point of view of another person.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> Stolen identity = lost money (most of the time)

Among the newborn I stay.

> You might say that since a baby has no pre-conceived opinions, he/she is able to be objective about him/herself.

Until they learn how to slay.

> When someone comes of age, he/she typically recieves some sort of ID card. At that point, they no longer define their own identity. Their identity is now defined by the system.

Two faces have I

One is true and the other to lie

> People often act one way when they are alone (the true identity), and a different way when they are around people (false identity).

Answer (score 0):

My try is:

> Health

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> You take me for grant but when I leave you cannot function.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> To regain me you pay the price of hospitals, doctors,...

Among the newborn I stay.

> Newborn is usually healthy.

Until they learn how to slay.

> When they learn to do bad things like drinking, smoking,...

Two faces have I
One is true and the other to lie

> one face says you have me forever and the other says will leave any moment.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> LIFE

I'm invisible until I'm lost.

> You take life for granted, unless you really think about it.

Once you lose me, you must pay the cost.

> Possibly a reference to video games with 1-ups given every 10000 or so points, or funeral cost

Among the newborn I stay.

> The newborn usually are living

Until they learn how to slay.

> Possibly a reference to Christianity in that you lose your soul when you commit a sin, thus slaying your soul

Two faces have I

> Life and Death, maybe?

One is true and the other to lie

> Another possible reference to Christianity in that if you lie, you die a spiritual death.